# Blazor - Targeting a specific user in SignalR

Tags: asp.net, blazor, signalr, asp.net-identity

We're developing a feature that will allow us to allow users to only use our product on one device at a time, and one of the prerequisites for this feature is the ability to remotely log out a given user without requiring any interaction on their end.

To achieve this, I'm using SignalR. The issue I'm facing is that when I trigger the log out command, nothing happens on the receiver's end. If `Client.All` is used, it works as intended (but logs out all users including the one sending the command). Interestingly, `Client.Others` doesn't log anyone out, when it seems like it should log out all other users than the one sending the command. However, the primary issue is that `Clients.User(userId)` isn't working.

The AuthHub is simple and consists of a single method to trigger the log out logic:

```
        public Task LogOut(string userId)
        {
            return Clients.User(userId).SendAsync("logOut");
        }
```

The command is triggered by this method:

```
        private async Task ForceLogout()
        {
            try
            {
                if (HubConnection is not null)
                {
                    await HubConnection.SendAsync("LogOut", User.Id);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                
            }
        }
```

And is received here:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(mNavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/authhub")) 
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On("logOut", async () =>
        {
            // Log out logic...
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

According to [Microsoft's documentation on managing users in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-7.0#users-in-signalr), "[b]y default, SignalR uses the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` from the ClaimsPrincipal associated with the connection as the user identifier." In that case, it's my understanding that this should be working, because the NameIdentifier claim type contains the UserId, which is what I'm passing in to the hub method call.

Using the debugger, I can see that the NameIdentifier part of the claim for the target user is the correct UserId, so I'm wondering what I'm missing here.

Comment: Put a break point in two places. One on `OnConnect` a hub override and another on a method. Inboth cases check the context to see if the use principal is making it to the hub. Signalr uses alternative transport systems to get the job done.  I have posted here in the past how to make sure the credentials are attached to the pipeline for Signalr Hubs. Do both as Connect and a method call may use different protocols.

Comment: Depending of the version of `SignalR` I thought the `User(...)` takes a `ConnectionId` not `UserId`. In the past I have had to map userId's to connectionId's in the `OnConnect` method. An alternative being place the user in a group with some sort of hash of the userId as a group name on connect. Then message that group...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the approach.

1. Need to create custom reference to identify device / any customized
   logic - referenceid.
2. Using the reference id and userid you can save
   the details and send the details to your signalrhub and logout can
   be achieved based on latest request.
3. Show the pop up window in the
   latest requested window to confirm.
4. logout in other devices  Once
   click on device you can logout other devices.